# How do I bypass the HTML encoding when using Html.ActionLink in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

Whenever I use Html.ActionLink it always Html encodes my display string. For instance I want my link to look like this:

```
<a href="/posts/422/My-Post-Title-Here">More&hellip;</a>
```

it outputs like this: [More&hellip;](/posts/422/My-Post-Title-Here)

&hellip is "..." incase you were wondering.

However the actionlink outputs the actual text "&hellip;" as the link text. I have the same problem with if I want to output this:

```
<a href="/posts/422/My-Post-Title-Here"><em>My-Post-Title-Here</em></a>
```

I wind up with:
[<em>My-Post-Title-Here</em>](/posts/422/My-Post-Title-Here)

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It looks like ActionLink always uses calls HttpUtility.Encode on the link text.  You could use UrlHelper to generate the href and build the anchor tag yourself.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Posts", ...)'>More&hellip;</a>
```

Alternatively you can "decode" the string you pass to ActionLink.  Constructing the link in HTML seems to be slightly more readable (to me) - especially in Razor.  Below is the equivalent for comparison.

```
@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("More&hellip;"), "Posts", ...)
```

Comment: @tvanfosson almost 4 years later... is this still the best method for stuffing special characters like ampersands, carets, etc. into link text?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer I think so, but there is an alternative which I've added.  Also updated to reflect Razor syntax.

Comment: Mvc Html extensions are all rubbish, for more power try Fubu MVC's HtmlTags library, you can then write your own (better) extension methods that return HtmlTags rather than MvcHtmlString

Comment: For MVC5 they renamed the Decode method to HtmlDecode
@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("More&hellip;"), "Posts", ...)

Answer (score 10):

The answer given by Sam is actually correct and I used it in my solution so I have therefore tried it myself.
You may want to remove the extra parenthesis so it becomes something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&amp;"), "Index", "Home")
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, just use a plain Unicode ellipsis character \u2026 and let MVC worry about how to encode it. Unless there's some particularly compelling reason you'd specifically need a hellip entity reference as opposed to a character reference or just including the character as simple UTF-8 bytes.

Alternative alternatively: just use three periods. The ellipsis (U+2026) is a compatibility character, only included to round-trip to pre-Unicode encodings. It gets you very little compared to simple dots.

Comment: The ellipsis is more semantically meaningful than three periods. It's also usually rendered more nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this:

```
  <p>Some text   @(new HtmlString(stringToPaste)) </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Decode it before passing the value in. Just had this same issue (different characters) and it works fine:

Eg:

```
@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_("&amp;")), "Index", "Home")
```

Annoying though