# Asp.Net Mvc Utilities and Helpers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm really new to ASP.Net Mvc, but not new to Asp.Net. I was aware of all of the HtmlHelper class, but I was having problems with ecoding issues using Html.ActionLink. I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422929/how-do-i-bypass-the-html-encoding-when-using-html-actionlink-in-mvc) and got an answer right away about using the UrlHelper class, which I had no idea even existed.

My question is, are there other classes like this that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice would be to have a quick scan through the classes in the [ASP.NET MVC beta source code](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18593). Reading the source of a library is by far the best way to become expert in its usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code to ASP.NET MVC at [www.codeplex.com/aspnet](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet).  Click the Source tab, choose a release, and navigate your way down the MVC tree to find all the MVC goodness.  Look in the Controller and View code to find the properties that are available to you from the base objects.

Answer (score 1):

- There is **[MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)** on CodePlex.
- My question similar to yours but [about ActionResults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486063/what-clever-things-have-you-done-with-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method) (didnt get many replies!)
- Not an MVC Helper, but I just found [SmartEnumerable](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) today from [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) by JonSkeet. Definitely very useful when generating data using `<% %>` notation becasue you can iterate through a collection and insert special logic depending upon whether or not the current item is the first or last item.

**Jon's example**:

```
foreach (SmartEnumerable<string>.Entry entry in
         new SmartEnumerable<string>(list))
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0,-7} {1} ({2}) {3}",
                       entry.IsLast  ? "Last ->" : "",
                       entry.Value,
                       entry.Index,
                       entry.IsFirst ? "<- First" : "");
}
```

**ASP.NET MVC**

`class="<% if (item.IsLast) ? "bulletpoint last" : "bulletpoint" %>"`