# Is it always safe to concatenate javascript files from different sources and load them as one?

Tags: javascript

I want to [concatenate javascript files together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486063/what-clever-things-have-you-done-with-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method) and serve them as one from my site - so thats my code and jquery plugins or other 3rd party scripts. (I'm using google CDN for hosting of jQuery).

I was wondering i this is **always** guaranteed to be a safe thing to do. I'm not an expert in Javascript as far as things like namespacing goes and I was just a little worried that it might be possible to have something - like a namespace construct that could cause a conflict. I'm fine in assuming that the javascript is all well formed from each source.

As far as I know a `<script>` tag essentially just sticks the JS in place as if it was in the file, but I wondered if theres any boundary cases where this isn't true.

I'm aware that concatenation of files is something that is common and used by javascript frameworks such as [Yahoo's YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/hosting/?layout#configure) - but obviously they have full control of their files.

Answer (score 3):

You may run into syntax errors around semi-colons.

file A:

```
var foo = 3 // END OF FILE
```

file B:

```
var bar = 4 // BEGINNING OF FILE
```

file A+B:

```
var foo = 3var bar = 4
```

Easily solved by just jamming a semi-colon between each file you are concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with krosenvold no reason why it shouldn't work that I can think off. Just make sure you watch your global variables and function names, they could cause problems if you get the scripts from multiple non-collaborating sources.

Comment: ya! javascript is scary. i'm sure this is a much more like source of a clash. its not like i'm not going to stop testing. i just wanted to make sure that there were no subtleties of concatenating dynamically .js files server side - especially since i presented my concatenating code for others to use

Answer (score 0):

As long as you concatenate them in the correct order you should be safe. The correct order is the same order as you load them in today.

Comment: so there is no such thing as anything being 'file scoped' in javascript?

Comment: @simon: the host object is shared on a window/frame level - files are irrelevant in this regard...