# Ampersand is being HTML Encoded as &amp;. Any way to prevent this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-encode, ampersand

I have the following block of code that creates an Action Link for a company.

```
Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(currentCompany.GetDisplayName()), "CompanyFactsheet", "Company",
                                                       new {friendlyURL = currentCompany.FriendlyURL.ToLower()}, null)%>
```

Some of the company names contain '&', and this is being rendered as `&amp;`

Is there a way that I can `Html.Encode` the company names, but still keep the `&` symbol as it's supposed to look, rather than `&amp;`?

Comment: Have you checked how the data is being stored?  Are you sure it's not being stored as "an &amp; example", which is actually being output to the source as "an &amp;amp; example"?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using and how are you outputting  Html.ActionLink (`<%:` or `<%=`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to encode when using ActionLink helper method. It encodes internally:

[How do I bypass the HTML encoding when using Html.ActionLink in Mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422929/how-do-i-bypass-the-html-encoding-when-using-html-actionlink-in-mvc/423025)

Answer (score 3):

Double check the markup that is getting generated. The only way that the `&amp;` should be showing on the page is if you're double encoding the ampersand character (so the source of the page would be showing `&amp;amp;`).

This could be caused by either storing the character already HTML encoded or you're using `<%:` (which HTML encodes everything for you automatically) instead of `<%=` in your View.

Comment: For Razor: I was reading from a txt file using `@Html.Encode(File.ReadAllText("..."))`, and it was double encoding the string. Switched to `@File.ReadAllText(...)` and now it only does it once.

Answer (score 0):

Replace & to some other charachter before saving them, and replace them back AFTER encoding (using jquery most likely)... I know it sounds like overkill, but if you really need the Html.Encode (or <%:, or @ in Razor), this is the best way IMHO....

Comment: It would be helpful to know why this got voted down. It actually worked for me. Perhaps someone willing to be a leader can share their thoughts.