# How to display an apostrophe in HTML for viewmodel string property

Tags: html, asp.net, ascii

My [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) view displays a client's name at the top of every page using a layout template. This works fine except when the name property is assigned a value that contains an apostrophe. The view displays the ascii code for the apostrophe instead of an actual apostrophe. For example:

if the client's name is set to "Client's Name", the view renders the name as `"Client&#39;s Name"` instead of "Client's Name"

Layout Template code:

```
    @helper ClientName()
    {
        if (Session["CurrentClient"] != null)
        {                                
            @(((ClientModel)Session["CurrentClient"]).Name);
        }
        else
        {
            @String.Format("{0}", "None");
        }
    }

    @Html.ActionLink("Client[" + @ClientName().ToString() + "]", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

What do I do to convert the string value to HTML so the apostrophe is shown?

Comment: "The view renders the name as `"Client&#39;s Name"`" But you only see a apostrophe because `&#39;` is an HTML entity, or does the HTML contain `&amp;#39;` and you actually see `&#39;` on the screen? Are you sure that `Session["CurrentClient"]).Name` isn't already HTML encoded?

Comment: I'm certain Session["CurrentClient"]).Name isn't already HTML encoded. The value is set to a string value from the database in the controller. So for a value of "King's Daughter", I'm actually seeing "King&#39;s Daughter"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10146258/227299. Also, post some proof that it's not already encoded.

If you try `@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Client[" + @ClientName().ToString() + "]"), "Index", "Home")` and it works, it would mean it's already encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146258/227299) `ActionLink` encodes what is passed in. Therefore, it's being double encoded.

Check the value of `@ClientName().ToString()`, that may already be encoded because helpers encode their output by default; you may need to un-encode it, or not encode it from your helper.

One solution is to make your helper [not escape its content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23604695/227299)

```
@{ WriteLiteral(((ClientModel)Session["CurrentClient"]).Name); }
```

or

```
@Html.Raw(((ClientModel)Session["CurrentClient"]).Name))
```

If you [must un-encode the results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146258/227299) of  `@ClientName().ToString()`, use

```
@Html.ActionLink(
   "Client[" + 
           HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@ClientName().ToString()) +
           "]",
   "Index", "Home")
```

Comment: I guess it was encoded after all. I know the data from the database isn't encoded and that's why I insisted that it wasn't. I watched it in the debugger to make sure. Guess the ActionLink() was encoding it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ihatemash Can you please add a comment explaining how you fixed your issue, since I provided two possibilities?

Comment: I used 
@Html.ActionLink("Client["+HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@ClientName().ToString()) + "]",  "Index", "Home")

and that fixed the problem.